# mysql update error for below queries

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am using follwing query to update.
my update function and connection string is in jar file.
I am using JSP useBean to call function from jar file.
I am able to run select queries on databse.
only getting problem in updating .
why I am getting this error now earlier it was working fine.

queries

```
String sql="INSERT INTO tm_visitor(VDT,VID,VISITOR_TEXT,COMPANY_TEXT,CONTACT,PERSON_TO_MEET,DEPARTMENT_TEXT,FLOOR)SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001),6,'0'),?,?,?,?,?,? FROM tm_visitor";
```

query2

```
String sql2="INSERT INTO tm_belonging(BID,BELONGING_TYPE,BELONGING_TEXT)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?,?)";
```

error:

```
Error in DBConnect  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Y
ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your M
ySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,? FROM tm_visito
r' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,? FROM tm_visitor' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1634)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1553)
        at com.vms.util.MyDBConnect.exeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jsp.applicationservices.fileshare.vm.apps.admin.visitorSub
mit_jsp._jspService(visitorSubmit_jsp.java:148)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
13)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:48
9)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error in DBConnect  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Y
ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your M
ySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1634)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1553)
        at com.vms.util.MyDBConnect.exeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jsp.applicationservices.fileshare.vm.apps.admin.visitorSub
mit_jsp._jspService(visitorSubmit_jsp.java:151)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3
13)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:48
9)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT

JSP CODE:

```
<jsp:useBean id="mdc" class="com.vms.util.MyDBConnect"/>
boolean status=false;

String VisitorName="",Company="",Contact="",WhomeToMeet="",Department="",DepartmentFloor="";
String Belonging="",BType="",Belonging2="",BType2="",Belonging3="",BType3="";
String Btype="",Belong="";
try
    {

VisitorName=(String)request.getParameter("VisitorName");
        out.println(","+VisitorName);
        Company=(String)request.getParameter("Company");
        out.println(","+Company);
        Contact=(String)request.getParameter("Contact");
        out.println(","+Contact);
        WhomeToMeet=(String)request.getParameter("WhomeToMeet");
        out.println(","+WhomeToMeet);
        Department=(String)request.getParameter("Department");
        out.println(","+Department);
        DepartmentFloor=(String)request.getParameter("DepartmentFloor");
        out.println(","+DepartmentFloor);
        BType=(String)request.getParameter("BType0");
        out.println(","+BType);
        Belonging=(String)request.getParameter("Belonging0");
        out.println(","+Belonging);
String sql="INSERT INTO tm_visitor(VDT,VID,VISITOR_TEXT,COMPANY_TEXT,CONTACT,PERSON_TO_MEET,DEPARTMENT_TEXT,FLOOR)SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001),6,'0'),?,?,?,?,?,? FROM tm_visitor";
        //System.out.println(sql);
        String sql2="INSERT INTO tm_belonging(BID,BELONGING_TYPE,BELONGING_TEXT)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?,?)";
        //System.out.println(sql2);
mdc.exeUpdate(sql);
mdc.exeUpdate(sql2);
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("eRROR>>\n"+e);
    }
```

Comment: What is the JSP code used to execute the first query?

Comment: @Jocelyn: I updated my question by adding jsp code

Comment: You're never sending values to bean so they can be used in the query

Comment: you're not adding the values into the query and I've never seen a select query like `SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001),6,'0'),?,?,?,?,?,? FROM tm_visitor` inside a insert query `INSERT INTO tm_visitor(VDT,VID,VISITOR_TEXT,COMPANY_TEXT,CONTACT,PERSON_TO_MEET,DEPARTMENT_TEXT,FLOOR)`

Comment: remove the select query inside the insert query and finish the insert query correctly

Comment: @ClydeFrog:It was working excellently before.And that select is use for getting MAX id from table to insert next id.

Comment: @ClydeFrog `INSERT INTO some_table SELECT * FROM other_table` is a valid syntax. [Read the manual for INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: have you edit some of the tables lately?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever yo use an ? in your statement, means that it will be "replaced" by a parameter.

You have to bind those paramters when executing the query.

Using standard JDBC syntax, it will be something like :

```
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepStmt.setString(1, paramValue1);
    prepStmt.setInt(2, paramValue2);
    ....
    prepStmt.setInt(n, paramValueN);
    prepStmt.execute();
```

Hope it helps